# flash to php to jpeg/gif?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I have a flash swf.  It lets people draw cool things (just a pen tool).  Now I want to have them be able to export it somehow to a website so they can view what they've made online.

Whats the best way to do this?

I know as3 and php right now, but do I need anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make sure your drawing is a BitmapData (using draw if it's a shape), then you can encode it to [JPEG](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=775) or [PNG](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib), and then send it to PHP using something like this: [Save ByteArray to file with PHP](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2006/05/01/save-bytearray-to-file-with-php/)

There are a few [GIF](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=93) encoders also, but I wouldn't recommend them for drawings.